# Searching a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I need to filter and do some math on data coming from CSV files.

I've wrote a simple Pyhton script to isolate the rows I need to get (they should contain certain keywords like "Kite"), but my script does not work and I can't find why. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? Another thing: once I get to the chosen row/s, how can I point to each (comma separated) column?

Thanks in advance.

R.

```
import csv

with open('sales-2013.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    sales = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in sales:
        if row == "Kite":
            print ",".join(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file in bytes. Change the `open('filepathAndName.csv, 'r')` command or convert your strings like `"Kite".encode('UTF-8')`. The second mistake could be that you are looking for a line with the word "Kite", but if "Kite" is a substring of that line it will not be found. In this case you have to use `if "Kite" in row:`.

```
with open('sales-2013.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: # <- change 'rb' to 'r'
    sales = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in sales:
        if row == "Kite": # <- this would be better: if "Kite" in row:
            print ",".join(row)
```

Read this:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, BUT what I noticed is if the first occurrence of the word "Kite" is "Kite-something" the row won't be picked. I need something like the old DOS command `*` (all). How do you express `"Kite*"` in python?

Comment: Use a RegExp like this: `re.match(r'Kite[\w|\W]*', row)`.

Comment: And please Vote up or check my answer if you are statisfied. :)

Comment: Thanks! when I try `if re.match(r'Kite[\w|\W]*', row) in row:` I get: `NameError: name 're' is not defined`. (I tried voting but I need 15 reputation points...)

Comment: you need `import re` on top of your script. And yes you can't vote but under the voting button is a button to accept the answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

To find the rows than **contain** the word "Kite", then you should use

```
for row in sales:   # here you iterate over every row (a *list* of cells)
    if "Kite" in row:
        # do stuff
```

Now that you know how to find the required rows, you can access the desired cells by indexing the rows. For example, if you want to select the second cell of a row, you simply do

```
cell = row[1]  # remember, indexes start with 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, BUT what I noticed is if the first occurrence of the word "Kite" is "Kite-something" the row won't be picked. I need something like the old DOS command 'asterisk' (all). How do you express "Kite 'asterisk' " in python?